# How to change Flutter ElevatedButton style with if condition?

Tags: flutter

If I want to create elevated button in flutter, and make background something like green if condition true, or blue if false

can I use if condition with elevated button?

Comment: style: isTrue? buttonStyle1 : buttonStyle2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `ButtonStyle`:

```
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Text('button'),
   style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.all( yourCondetion ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,),
        ),
   ),
```

if you want to use `ElevatedButton.styleFrom`:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('button'),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: yourCondetion ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `styleFrom` to style an **ElevatedButton**:

```
      ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Button'),
        onPressed: () {},
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom({
          (condition) ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        }),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('My Button')
  onPress: () {}
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary:  isTrue? Colors.green : Colors.blue
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable with type `ButtonStyle`. We often use a file which includes every button style.

Ex: file `button_style.dart`:

```
var btnStyleGreen = ButtonStyle(color: green)

var btnStyleBlue = ButtonStyle(color: blue)
```

Your working file:

```
ButtonStyle yourBtnStyle;
if (isBlue) yourBtnStyle = btnStyleGreen; else yourBtnStyle = btnStyleGreen;

ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Button'),
  onPress: () {},
  style: yourBtnStyle,
)
```

That's how a big product often does.

Answer (score 1):

```
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Text('button'),
   style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.all( yourCondetion ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,),
        ),
   )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).